# Hausdorff dimension of sets with positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

I am reading [*Hausdorff Dimension, Its Properties, and Its Surprises*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642249?seq=1) by Dierk Schleicher. Among the elementary properties of the Hausdorff dimension, the last one is:

> If $X\subset \Bbb R^n$ has finite positive $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, then $\dim_H X = d$.

*My work.* It will be enough to show that $\mathcal H^s(X) = 0$ for all $s > d$, and $\mathcal H^s(X) = \infty$ for all $s < d$. As usual, $$H^s(X) = \lim_{\delta\to 0} H^s_\delta(X)$$
where $$\mathcal H^s_\delta(X) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |U_i|^s: \{U_i\} \text{ is a }\delta\text{-cover of }X  \right\}$$

I'm unable to relate the Lebesgue measure with coverings of $X$, which would help me find a connection with $\mathcal H^s_\delta(X)$ for given $\delta > 0$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the definition of $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$ for $d<n$? I realize I haven't run across this definition before, probably because usually we use the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for that purpose, but if there is a definition other than $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, I think it needs to be recalled here so this question can get a properly complete answer. With respect to my answer, I am not even sure the isodiametric inequality in the form I stated it makes sense without a definition of what $\mathcal L^d$ means when $d < n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer only addresses the case $n = d$!

Note that an equivalent definition of the Hausdorff measure is obtained by using convex sets of diameter at most $\delta$ instead of arbitrary $\delta$-covers since any set of diameter $\delta$ is contained in a convex set of diameter $\delta$.

Let $|E|$ denote the diameter of a set $E$, let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $\{U_i\}$ be a cover of $X$ by convex sets such that
$$
\sum_i |U_i|^d \le \mathcal H^d(X)+\epsilon.
$$
You can show for any convex set $U\subset\mathbb R^d$, its Lebesgue measure satisfies $\mathcal L^d(U)\le c_d |U|^d$. (This is a form of the isodiametric inequality in $\mathbb R^d$.) Then,
$$
\mathcal L^d(X)\le \sum_i\mathcal L^d(U_i) \le c_d\sum_i|U_i|^d\le c_d(\mathcal H^d(X)+\epsilon).
$$
Letting $\epsilon\to 0$, this shows the inequality $\mathrm{dim}_HX\ge d$. For each $X\subset \mathbb R^d$, $\dim_HX\le d$, so this proves the claim in this special case.

Comment: Assuming I fill in the details, we take $\epsilon \to 0$ in the last step, right? That gives $\mathcal L^d(X) > 0 \implies \mathcal H^d(X) > 0$, which only tells me that $\dim_H X \ge d$. I believe we also need to show $\dim_H X \le d$.

Comment: @connected-subgroup: My apologies, I misread the question as $d$ being the dimension of the ambient Euclidean space. In such a case, the inequality $\mathrm{dim}_HX\ge d$ also implies $\mathrm{dim}_HX = d$. I am not sure the isodiametric inequality still applies in the case $n > d$. I will edit my answer to reflect that this answer only addresses a special case of the problem.

Comment: Just want to confirm how we get the cover $\{U_i\}$. Suppose for all coverings $\{U_i\}$ of $X$, $$\sum_i |U_i|^d > \mathcal H^d(X) + \epsilon$$
In particular, this is true for $\delta$-covers also. Taking infimum over all $\delta$-covers, we get $$\mathcal H^d_\delta(X) \ge \mathcal H^d(X) + \epsilon$$
However, we know that $\mathcal H^d_\delta(X)$ increases (or stays constant) as $\delta\to 0$, and $\mathcal H^d(X) = \lim_{\delta\to 0}\mathcal H^d_\delta(X)$, so $$\mathcal H^d(X) \ge \mathcal H^d_\delta(X) \ge \mathcal H^d(X) + \epsilon$$
which is absurd, since $\epsilon > 0$. $(1/2)$

Comment: Therefore, we can find a convex $\delta$-cover $\{U_i\}$ satisfying $$\sum_i |U_i|^d \le \mathcal H^d(X) + \epsilon$$ If there's an easier way to see this, let me know! $(2/2)$.

Comment: For showing $$\mathcal L^d(U)\le c_d |U|^d$$ where $U\subset\Bbb R^d$ is convex, here, are my thoughts: We can enclose $U$ in a ball of radius $|U|$, and the Lebesgue measure of a ball of radius $r$ in $\Bbb R^d$ is known to be proportional to $r^d$. I believe that's enough?

Comment: Hi Alex! Could you please reply to my comments here?

Comment: @connected-subgroup: Apologies for the late reply! The details you provided look complete to me :-)